# Whats the formula to calculate width & height, when given a resolution and ratio

Tags: divisibility

Let's say I have a puzzle, which says it has `1000` pieces. I also know it's a `4:3` ratio picture that I'm trying to put together. **How do I calculate the width & height in number of pieces?**

I know that if I knew the puzzle was `1000` pieces wide, it would have a `750` pieces height, since thats a `4:3` ratio. But I don't know the width/height, only the calculated resolution.

`? x ? = 1000`

I started with a square root, giving me the number of ± `31.62`, which would be right if the puzzle was a square, but it's in the `4:3` ratio.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that it goes as follows: If $l$ is the number of pieces along the short side, then $\frac{4}{3}l$ is the number of pieces along the long side. The total number of pieces is then $\frac{4}{3}l^2=1000$, and we can solve for $l$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a description of why Bran van der Meer's answer works:

Consider
$$
wh=1000
$$
and
$$
\frac wh=\frac43
$$
Multiply these to get
$$
w^2=1000\times\frac43
$$
Divide them to get
$$
h^2=1000\times\frac34
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If the number of pieces in the short direction is $x$, the number in the long direction is $\frac 43x$.  The total number of pieces is then ???  Now solve for $x$